# Helm upgrade with values and namespace

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I need to upgrade some values in helm chart:

```
EC2-TEST@~>helm list -A
NAME    NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART           APP VERSION
jenkins jenkins     1           2021-06-23 09:21:28.245050889 +0000 UTC deployed    jenkins-3.4.0   2.289.1
```

```
EC2-TEST@~>helm repo list
NAME        URL
jenkinsci   https://charts.jenkins.io
```

Chart deployed using:

```
helm install jenkins -n jenkins -f jenkins-values.yaml
```

New changed yaml chart in the same folder with the name `new-values-jenkins.yaml`

Tried a lot of variaations, looks like a syntax issue, getting the following errors:

```
Error: "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments

Usage:  helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]
```

or:

```
error: file '/home/ec2-user/jenkins-values.yaml' seems to be a YAML file, but expected a gzipped archive
```

variations I tried

```
EC2-TEST@~>helm upgrade -f Jenkins-default-helm.yaml jenkins ./jenkins-values.yaml
Error: file '/home/ec2-user/jenkins-values.yaml' seems to be a YAML file, but expected a gzipped archive
EC2-TEST@~>helm upgrade -f Jenkins-default-helm.yaml jenkins ./jenkins-values.yaml -n jenkins
Error: file '/home/ec2-user/jenkins-values.yaml' seems to be a YAML file, but expected a gzipped archive
EC2-TEST@~>helm upgrade ./jenkins-values.yaml -f Jenkins-default-helm.yaml -n jenkins
Error: "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments

Usage:  helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]
EC2-TEST@~>helm upgrade ./jenkins-values.yaml -f Jenkins-default-helm.yaml
Error: "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments

Usage:  helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]
EC2-TEST@~>helm upgrade jenkins  ./jenkins-values.yaml -f Jenkins-default-helm.yaml
Error: file '/home/ec2-user/jenkins-values.yaml' seems to be a YAML file, but expected a gzipped archive
EC2-TEST@~>helm upgrade jenkins ./jenkins-values.yaml --values ./Jenkins-default-helm.yaml -n jenkins
Error: file '/home/ec2-user/jenkins-values.yaml' seems to be a YAML file, but expected a gzipped archive
EC2-TEST@~>helm upgrade jenkins jenkinsci/jenkins-3.4.0 --values ./Jenkins-default-helm.yaml -n jenkins
Error: failed to download "jenkinsci/jenkins-3.4.0" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
EC2-TEST@~>helm upgrade jenkins https://charts.jenkins.io --values ./Jenkins-default-helm.yaml -n jenkins
Error: failed to download "https://charts.jenkins.io" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
EC2-TEST@~>helm upgrade jenkins --values Jenkins-default-helm.yaml --namespace jenkins
Error: "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments

Usage:  helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]
EC2-TEST@~>helm upgrade jenkins-values.yaml --values Jenkins-default-helm.yaml --namespace jenkins
Error: "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments

Usage:  helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]
EC2-TEST@~>helm upgrade jenkins --values Jenkins-default-helm.yaml -n jenkins
Error: "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments

Usage:  helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]
EC2-TEST@~>helm upgrade  --values Jenkins-default-helm.yaml -n jenkins
Error: "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments

Usage:  helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]
EC2-TEST@~>helm upgrade jenkins -f Jenkins-default-helm.yaml -n jenkins
Error: "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments

Usage:  helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]
EC2-TEST@~>helm upgrade jenkins -f Jenkins-default-helm.yaml -n jenkins
Error: "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments

Usage:  helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]
EC2-TEST@~>helm upgrade jenkins -f Jenkins-default-helm.yaml
Error: "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments

Usage:  helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]
EC2-TEST@~>helm upgrade -n jenkins  jenkins -f Jenkins-default-helm.yaml
Error: "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments

Usage:  helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]
EC2-TEST@~>helm upgrade -n jenkins  jenkins --values Jenkins-default-helm.yaml
Error: "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments

Usage:  helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]
EC2-TEST@~>helm upgrade -n jenkins jenkins --values Jenkins-default-helm.yaml
Error: "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments

Usage:  helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]
EC2-TEST@~>helm upgrade jenkins --values Jenkins-default-helm.yaml -n jenkins
Error: "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments

Usage:  helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]
EC2-TEST@~>helm upgrade jenkins --values Jenkins-default-helm.yaml --namespace jenkins
Error: "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments

Usage:  helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]
EC2-TEST@~>helm upgrade jenkins-v --values Jenkins-default-helm.yaml --namespace jenkins
jenkins-values.yaml  jenkins-volume.yaml
EC2-TEST@~>helm upgrade jenkins-v --values Jenkins-default-helm.yaml --namespace jenkins
jenkins-values.yaml  jenkins-volume.yaml
EC2-TEST@~>helm upgrade jenkins-values.yaml --values Jenkins-default-helm.yaml --namespace jenkins
Error: "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments

Usage:  helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]
```

Any help with the proper syntax (including the namespace?)

Appriciate!. (an option with a rollback will be nice also, just in case)

** ref: https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/

Comment: Could you include at least some of the variations you tried on the upgrade? Error message should be self-explanatory.

Comment: Added most of the variations I've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the issue is that you are missing actual chart reference in the command. In that sense your install command is incorrect also (maybe this part was lost due to copy-paste issue initially or something).

Your install command should be:

```
helm install jenkins -n jenkins -f jenkins-values.yaml jenkinsci/jenkins
```

And your upgrade command should be:

```
helm upgrade jenkins -n jenkins -f jenkins-values.yaml jenkinsci/jenkins
```

or with your other values file:

```
helm upgrade jenkins -n jenkins -f Jenkins-default-helm.yaml jenkinsci/jenkins
```

Essentially, notice that you are missing the actual chart reference - the `jenkinsci/jenkins` part.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, using jenkins/jenkins as my chart

```
helm ls -n jenkins
NAME    NAMESPACE       REVISION        UPDATED                                 STATUS          CHART           APP VERSION
jenkins jenkins         46              2023-04-15 12:19:49.9738769 +0800 +08   deployed        jenkins-4.1.9   2.332.3

helm upgrade jenkins jenkins/jenkins --version x.x.x -n jenkins -f <values.yml> --dry-run --debug
```